# supply `idgen` attribute in INSERT WFS transaction

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I am able to update vector features in GeoServer with JavaScript code using the `OpenLayers v6.5.0` library in the below straightforward manner:

```
const featureRequest = wfs.writeTransaction(
[],        // inserts
[feature], // updates
[],        //deletes
{
  srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
  featureNS: 'https://geoserver.anon.com/',
  featurePrefix: 'coredb',
  featureType: 'eae_field_geospatial_data'
});

return fetch('https://geoserver.anon.com/geoserver/coredb/ows', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
 }).then( (response) => {
   // handle response
 });
```

The above works well for updates but not for inserts. I posted a question at [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/385756/158056) but after considerable investigation it was discovered that the problem lies with the WFS payload generated by open layers, namely the below payload is missing the `idgen` attribute at the `Insert` node. So the below code fails since it completely disregards the feature id (`555`) I supply and computes its own value.

If OTOH, the following was used: `<Insert idgen="UseExisting">`, then the `INSERT` to the database succeeds.

The problem is I don't see any options for passing the `idgen` parameter in the `WFS` functionality [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_WFS-WFS.html).

Any ideas?

Below is the payload that fails due to the lack of the `idgen` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Insert>
    <eae_stable_mapping xmlns="coredb" fid="eae_stable_mapping.555">
      <geometry>
        <MultiPolygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857">
          <polygonMember>
            <Polygon srsName="EPSG:3857">
              <exterior>
                <LinearRing srsName="EPSG:3857">
                  <posList srsDimension="2">2441824.1162386383 4829505.778704044 2444124.9240303603 4828797.839673139 2442886.0247849966 4831806.586495766 2441824.1162386383 4829505.778704044</posList>
                </LinearRing>
              </exterior>
            </Polygon>
          </polygonMember>
        </MultiPolygon>
      </geometry>
      <stable_id>555</stable_id>
    </eae_stable_mapping>
  </Insert>
</Transaction>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up patching the request created by the OpenLayers library as follows (note: code is edited, some details omitted):

```
import {Feature} from 'ol';

function insert_feature(f: Feature) {

  const featureRequest = wfs.writeTransaction(
    [f], [], []
    options
  );


  patchFeatureRequest(featureRequest)
    
  fetch('https://geoserver.iacs.lab.synelixis.com/geoserver/coredb/ows', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
    }).then( (response) => {
       // do sth with the response
    });
}             

function patchFeatureRequest(fr: Node) {
    const insertElement: Element = Array.from(fr.childNodes.values())[0]
    insertElement.setAttribute('idgen', 'UseExisting');
}
```